# Assist with USPS API using PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl

Hello I am trying to do API call to USPS API using PHP Curl.

I get the following response:

```
[Number] => 80040B19
[Description] => XML Syntax Error: Please check the XML request to see if it can be parsed.
[Source] => USPSCOM::DoAuth
```

I put together my code for the API call from some sample code on here and also the sample on the USPS site; but cannot get it to work (getting error above); here is my code:

```
$input_xml = '<AddressValidateRequest USERID="xxxxxxx">
<Address ID="0">
    <Address1></Address1>
    <Address2>6406 Ivy Lane</Address2><City>Greenbelt</City>
<State>MD</State>
<Zip5></Zip5>
<Zip4></Zip4>
</Address>
</AddressValidateRequest>';

$url = "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=Verify";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                "xmlRequest=" . $input_xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    //convert the XML result into array
    $array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($data)), true);

    print_r('<pre>');
    print_r($array_data);
    print_r('</pre>');
```

I am hoping someone can help with what I am doing wrong...

Comment: ... that is disturbingly close to my address as a child. And you're missing the opening `<` in front of `City`

Comment: check  `<City>Greenbelt</City>` it is missing the opening

Comment: @SeanBright  you should be careful posting that info, someone may travel back in time and kidnap you to prevent you from commenting to this post in the future

Comment: Hello Guys: thanks for responding but actually my code had that opening tag in it and when i put it on here i mistakenly deleted it; so sorry about wasting your time on finding that error; i edited it and it still gets that error so if you can find anything else wrong please let me know....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information-api.htm), you're supposed to pass the XML in a field named `XML`, not `xmlRequest`. Try something like this instead:

```
<?php
$input_xml = <<<EOXML
<AddressValidateRequest USERID="xxxxxxx">
    <Address ID="0">
        <Address1></Address1>
        <Address2>6406 Ivy Lane</Address2>
        <City>Greenbelt</City>
        <State>MD</State>
        <Zip5></Zip5>
        <Zip4></Zip4>
    </Address>
</AddressValidateRequest>
EOXML;

$fields = array(
    'API' => 'Verify',
    'XML' => $input_xml
);

$url = 'http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?' . http_build_query($fields);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Convert the XML result into array
$array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($data)), true);

print_r('<pre>');
print_r($array_data);
print_r('</pre>');
?>
```

Comment: thanks so much Sean...that did work although i had to edit a litte; it did not like the way you did the "$fields" array and got an error; but that was something I knew how to handle so i basically redid your exact array a little differently - but could not have done this without your help so thanks so much (I will edit your answer for the array part)

Comment: Looks like you're running an older PHP version that doesn't support the `[…]` array syntax. I've updated to show how to do it with the older `array(…)` syntax.

Comment: yeah - i am sure you are right; i actually tried to do it with parens as I thought it could be done that way; but could not remember exactly how it went; so fastest way to do it was the way i knew like the back of my hand...thanks so much!